# Not able to add same component twice inside the dynamic placeholder

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce

I have created one component and inside that main component cshtml page, added one DynamicPlaceholder, in-order to add another component twice for configurations. First time, when I drag and drop the required component using ToolBox it is working fine and I am able to add the component along with required configurations but when I am trying to do the same thing twice, the Placeholder is not working and restricting to add the component using toolbox but when I try to add the same thing using "Add Here" button without using toolbox it is working properly.

Comment: Can you share some more details? may be some screenshots that might help.

Comment: @Gautam Added more details in the problem statement..!!

Comment: If it is allowing you with the "Add here" button then it should also allow you with drag and drop, may be you are dropping the component at wrong position, can you share some screenshot how it is restricting you?

Comment: I would guess you are dragging to the wrong place or your component contains a JavaScript error/code that is blocking the drag functionality. If it worked the first time, no reason why it wouldn't work the second time unless your component was doing something to prevent the drop.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I have also tried on my end and found the same issues. I also checked the JS code or console error but found nothing impacted the dragging of the component to the placeholder. I would guess it's a Sitecore SXA issue and we might need to create a support ticket.